# C++ segmentation fault when accessing class member in main()

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, initialization, sublimetext3

Basically I am creating a mesh composed of nodes and springs and I keep receiving the segmentation fault (core dumped) error when trying to access an element of the `nodes` vector defined in the `Mesh` class in `main()`.

When I run a test output within the `Mesh` class' constructor, I can access the node member just fine. I'm sure it's a memory problem but could anyone explain why this is happening?

Node class:

```
class Node
{ 

public:

 /// (Non-)magic number indicating that the coordinate has not
 /// been classified as pinned or free yet
 static int Not_classified_yet;

 /// (Non-)magic number indicating that the coordinate is pinned
 static int Is_pinned;

 /// Constructor: Pass the spatial dimension
 Node(const unsigned& dim)
  {
   // Resize
   X.resize(dim,0.0);
   Eqn_number.resize(dim,Not_classified_yet);
  }


 /// Function to add a spring to the node
 void add_spring_pt(Spring* spring_pt)
  {
   Spring_pt.push_back(spring_pt);
  }

 /// How many springs are attached to this node?
 unsigned nspring()
  {
   return Spring_pt.size();
  }

 /// Access function to the ith spring connected to the node
 Spring*& spring_pt(const unsigned& i)
  {
   return Spring_pt[i];
  }
 /// Access function to the position vector of the node
  vector<double>& get_vector()
  {
    return X;
  }

 /// Access function to the coordinates of the node
 double& x(int i)
  {
   return X[i];
  }

 /// Access function to the equation number for each coordinate 
 /// Can be negative if node is pinned in that direction.
 int& eqn_number(const unsigned& i)
  {
   return Eqn_number[i];
  }


 /// Pin the i-th coordinate
 void pin(const unsigned& i)
  {
   Eqn_number[i]=Is_pinned;
  }

 /// Is the i-th coordinate pinned?
 bool is_pinned(const unsigned& i)
  {
   return (Eqn_number[i]==Is_pinned);
  }


private:

 /// Pointers to the springs attatched to the node. 
 vector<Spring*> Spring_pt;

 /// Coordinates of the node
 vector<double> X;

 /// Vector containing equation indices for each coordinate direction.
 /// Can be negative if node is pinned in that direction.
 vector<int> Eqn_number;

};
```

Mesh class:

```
class Mesh
{
 public:
    /// constructor (nX contains number of nodes in each direction)
  Mesh(const vector<unsigned> nX)
  { 
    /// Function "num_nodes" defined in "myFunctions.cpp" to find the 
    /// total number of nodes.
    unsigned nNodes = num_nodes(nX);
    /// Check the dimension of the mesh and and construct a vector
    /// of the nodes.
    unsigned dim = nX.size();
    vector<Node> nodes(nNodes,dim);
    //std::cout<< nodes[1].x(0)<<std::endl;
    /// Function "num_springs" defined in "myFunctions.cpp" to find the
    /// total number of springs.
    unsigned nsprings = num_springs(nX);
    /// Vector to hold the springs.
    vector<Spring> springs(nsprings);
    /// Function to assign coordinates to all the nodes.
    assign_coordinates(nodes,nX);
  }
    /// Access function to the ith node of the mesh.
    Node& node(const unsigned& i)
    {
        return nodes[i];
    }

  /// Function declaration for assigning coordinates to nodes
  void assign_coordinates(std::vector<Node>& nodes, std::vector<unsigned> nX);

    /// Access function to the ith spring of the mesh.
    Spring& spring(const unsigned& i)
    {
        return springs[i];
    }

private:
  /// Declare vectors to hold the nodes and springs.
  vector<Node> nodes;
  vector<Spring> springs;
};
```

And what I am trying to output from the main():

```
int main()
{
  // create a mesh
  // spatial dimensions
  unsigned nx = 3;
  unsigned ny = 3;
  unsigned nz = 3;
  vector<unsigned> nX(2);
  nX[0] = nx;
  nX[1] = ny;
  //nX[2] = nz;
  Mesh m(nX);

  // segmentation fault (core dumped)
  std::cout << m.node(6).eqn_number(1) << std::endl;
};
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (a problem?) is in `Mesh` constructor when you define

```
 vector<Node> nodes(nNodes,dim);
```

I suppose that your intention was initialize the `nodes` member of the `Mesh` class; what you get is a `nodes` variable that is local to the `Mesh` constructor.

The `nodes` member of `Mesh` is initialized with the implicit default constructor, so the vectors in the `Node`s (`Spring_pt`, `X` and `Eqn_number`) are initialized with the default `std::vector` constructor so with zero size.

When you call

```
m.node(6).eqn_number(1)
```

with `node(6)` you call the 7th element of a `std::vector` of size zero.

Same problem with

```
std::vector<Spring> springs(nsprings);
```

in the `Mesh` constructor: you declare and initialize a `springs` variable local in the constructor where your intention (I suppose) was initialize the `springs` member of `Mesh`.

If I understand correctly your intentions, you should be able to solve the problem writing your constructor as follows

```
  Mesh (const std::vector<unsigned> nX)
     : nodes(num_nodes(nX), nX.size()), springs(num_springs(nX))
   { assign_coordinates(nodes,nX); }
```

Comment: Thanks Max that's letting me access the nodes now, and it reads much better also.

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance it looks like you initialized your mesh with 2 nodes and then went asking for the 7th (indexed starting at 0).

A quick way to check for this is to change `nodes[i]` to `nodes.at(i)` which will enable out-of-bounds checking for vector element accesses.

Comment: Jim, thanks for the reply but I have actually initialized my mesh with a vector of the spatial dimension, ie [3,3] so the num_nodes function tells the mesh there is 3x3 = 27 nodes in the mesh. So looking for the 7th node should be fine.

Comment: @mbbxadam  My mistake!  Even so, switching to `.at()` can help troubleshooting this kind of error when it gets through to runtime.

Comment: Ok I'll make note of that and be sure to use it